# PARTITION BY row value

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to partition my output table when a certain row is of a certain value. I have:

```
ID|Value|User
-------------
1 |A    |Rick
2 |A    |Rick
3 |B    |Rick
7 |A    |Rick
8 |C    |Rick
4 |A    |Joe
5 |B    |Joe
6 |B    |Joe
```

I need to partition my table for each individual user, and when the value = A, so what I need is:

```
Row|ID|Value|User
------------------
1  |1 |A    |Rick 
1  |2 |A    |Rick
2  |3 |B    |Rick
1  |7 |A    |Rick
2  |8 |C    |Rick
1  |4 |A    |Joe
2  |5 |B    |Joe
3  |6 |B    |Joe
```

Every value has its own ID.

I've tried things like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User, Value = A ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row, Value, User FROM...
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User, WHERE Value = A ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row, Value, User FROM...
etc
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to write it correctly, if it even is possible.

Comment: what is the logic of what you want? from your data i can see "A" and "Rick" is 1 and 
 "A" and "Joe" is also 1 ect. how does that come about?

Comment: What do you mean? If you need it, you can imagine Value to be something like car types with A being Ferrari or whatever

Comment: As the question has now been changed, this is now impossible. There is nothing in your data to maintain the order of it using an `ORDER BY`. Tables are inherently unordered, so  the`'A'` that appears "below" a `'B'` in your table in your question could be anywhere in the table.

Comment: Every Value has a unique ID, would that make it possible?

Comment: I don't see that it would make it possible, because you are not showing the IDs in order, implying that some other sort of order is what you need - what is the order you have shown your records in?

Comment: Each ID is unique, its just that I ordered them by User and not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you're after is simply a `DENSE_RANK`:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Value] ASC) AS [Row]
```

*Note `USER` is a reserved keyword in T-SQL. I strongly recommend you chose a different name for your column, as you must otherwise delimit identify it. `ROW` and `VALUE` are not currently reserved, but they are listed as a [Future Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#future-keywords) and their use is also recommended to be avoided.*

Edit: Seems, actually that it's `'A'` is `1`, and then also increment afterwards. This is messy, but you could therefore you could do:

```
SELECT CASE [Value]
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Value]) -
                 COUNT(CASE [Value] WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [User]) + 1
       END AS [Row],
       V.[Value],
       V.[User]
FROM (VALUES ('A', 'Rick'),
             ('A', 'Rick'),
             ('B', 'Rick'),
             ('C', 'Rick'),
             ('A', 'Joe '),
             ('B', 'Joe '),
             ('B', 'Joe ')) V ([Value], [User]);
```

This **assumes** that there will always be at least one row with `'A'`.

Edit 2: Ok, goal posts were moved again, this now does what you are after. If they move again, you will need to amend the solution though:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.Value,
           V.[User]
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A','Rick'),
                (2,'A','Rick'),
                (3,'B','Rick'),
                (7,'A','Rick'),
                (8,'C','Rick'),
                (4,'A','Joe '),
                (5,'B','Joe '),
                (6,'B','Joe '))V(ID,[Value],[User])),
Grps AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.Value,
           YT.[User],
           COUNT(CASE YT.[Value] WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY YT.[User] ORDER BY YT.ID) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable YT)
SELECT ID,
       CASE G.[Value]
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.[User], G.Grp ORDER BY G.[Value]) -
                 COUNT(CASE G.[Value] WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY G.[User], G.Grp) + 1
       END AS [Row],
       G.[Value],
       G.[User]
FROM Grps G
ORDER BY G.[User], G.ID;
```

Comment: Not really, as Joe for example has the Value B twice, but Row should keep incrementing. Or is there a way to do that with DENSE_RANK()?
Also, I use fake names for my rows here, no need to worry about the User row name. but thanks nonetheless for the heads up!

Comment: So it's always 1 at `'A'` and then increments regardless, @PAT_The_Whale ?

Comment: Messy, but based on that logic, the bottom version works.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It starts a 2 and just increments as if the ```CASE Value WHEN 'A' THEN 1``` didn't exist.
My work shift is over, so I'll only continue tomorrow.

Comment: It works for me, @PAT_The_Whale : [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a042203648b04f219517d3e77c013de4). Why i included DDL and DML. If it's not, then you're not telling us something.

Comment: I just realized, this works _almost_ perfectly. Lets say Rick has an A value between his B and C values. The counter doesn't reinitialize. I know it wasn't added in the question, but I just now noticed that this scenario can happen

Comment: No, that scenario wasn't in your question, @PAT_The_Whale  and it is now impossible to solve with the data you have. How do you define that another `'A'` is other a `'B'` when you have nothing to maintain that order by use of an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I know it wasn't in the question and I apologize. Every Value has a Unique ID. Does that make it possible?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't in your sample either, @PAT_The_Whale . Please stop moving the goal posts, you're wasting the time of those you are asking for help from, and that is going to have your question ignored or downvoted.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll do better in future posts. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Have added *another* answer, @PAT_The_Whale . Please don't move the goal posts again.

Comment: It works perfectly, I just had to make a small change: ```ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.[User], G.Grp ORDER BY G.[Value])``` The ORDER BY was changed to ```ORDER BY G.ID```. Thanks a ton for this!

Answer (score 0):

How about this - A is always 1, I wind row back to 1 if an A appears, then I always increment by 1 if it is not A

```
With CTE AS (select *, row_number() OVER (order by [user], value) as RN from theTable)

select CASE WHEN C1.Value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 1 +  C1.RN - C.RN  END [row] ,  * from 
            CTE C1 OUTER APPLY 
              (SELECT TOP 1 RN FROM CTE C2 
                                WHERE C2.RN < C1.RN AND C2.Value = 'A' 
                                ORDER BY C2.RN DESC) C
```

Comment: I don't think yours works. Not only is it extremely slow (over 4,30 minutes for 900 rows), the Row number sometimes leaps from 1 to 8 for example, despite the User only having 2 Values

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(
    RowNumber   INT
    ,[Value]    CHAR(5)
    ,[User]     VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table
(
    [Value]
    ,[User]
)
values
 ('A','Rick') 
,('A','Rick')
,('B','Rick')
,('C','Rick')
,('A','Joe ')
,('B','Joe ')
,('B','Joe ')


    select 
        RowNumber       = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Value] ASC) 
        ,[User]
        ,[Value]
    from 
        @Table
    WHERE
        [Value] = 'A'
UNION ALL
    select 
        RowNumber       = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Value] ASC)  + 1
        ,[User]
        ,[Value]
    from 
        @Table
    WHERE
        [Value] != 'A'
    Order BY
        [User] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `DENSE_RANK()` will work as in your example `B` would have the same value

```
2  |B    |Joe
2  |B    |Joe
```

instead of

```
2  |B    |Joe
3  |B    |Joe
```

The best way I've come up with is a two pass method

1. Use normal `ROW_NUMBER()` -> `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.value) AS rn`
2. Then Use `DENSE_RANK()` -> `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY IIF(c.value = 'a', NULL, c.rn))`
3. The trick here is the `ORDER BY` where we NULL it based on a condition `IIF(c.value = 'a', NULL, c.rn))`

```
WITH 
    cte_dataset ([value], [name])
  AS (SELECT 'A' AS v, 'Rick' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'A' AS v, 'Rick' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'B' AS v, 'Rick' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'C' AS v, 'Rick' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'A' AS v, 'Joe' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'B' AS v, 'Joe' AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'B' AS v, 'Joe' AS n)
   , cte_add_simple_order
  AS (
    SELECT 
        c.value, 
        c.name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.value) AS rn 
    FROM cte_dataset c
    )
SELECT
    c.value
  , c.name
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY IIF(c.value = 'a', NULL, c.rn))
FROM cte_add_simple_order c
ORDER BY
    c.name DESC
  , c.value ;
```

```
|value|name|Rank|
|A    |Rick|1   |
|A    |Rick|1   |
|B    |Rick|2   |
|C    |Rick|3   |
|A    |Joe |1   |
|B    |Joe |2   |
|B    |Joe |3   |
```

Comment: If you have another column in the source table such as an `IDENTITY()` (_and that is how you want the order to be_), you can skip the `cte_add_simple_order` and use this directly.

`DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY IIF(c.value = 'a', NULL, unique_ordered_or_identity_column))`